# Ejabberd 18.12.1 - X-OAUTH2 fails with invalid token - How to setup?

Tags: oauth-2.0, xmpp, ejabberd

I am successfully running ejabberd 18.12 debian stretch backport using a sqlite database as default and ldap authentication for about 2 years.

Recently I ran into an application which only supports xmpp authentication via oauth so I tried to set that up without success.

My config looks as follows:

```
hosts:
  - "domain.local"

certfiles:
   - "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

default_db: sql
sql_type: sqlite
sql_database: "/var/lib/ejabberd/ejabberd.sqlite"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    starttls_required: true
    tls_compression: false
    ciphers: "HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!RSA@STRENGTH"
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
      - "no_sslv2"
      - "no_tlsv1"
      - "cipher_server_preference"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    zlib: true

  -
    port: 5443
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    dhfile: "/etc/ejabberd/dhparams.pem"
    tls_compression: false
    ciphers: "HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!RSA@STRENGTH"
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv2"
      - "no_sslv3"
      - "no_tlsv1"
      - "cipher_server_preference"
    request_handlers:
      "files": mod_http_upload
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      "/api": mod_http_api


oauth_expire: 2592000
oauth_access: all

auth_method: [ldap,internal]

acl:
  admin:
     user:
         - "admin": "domain.local"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"


access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow: all
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal: all
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc:
    - allow: all
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  register:
    - deny: all
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback
```

According to the official howto oauth is only available for internal users stored in the mnesia database. ([Ejabberd Support oauth](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/oauth/)

Consequently I created a local user via the ejabberd console for my test which does not authenticate against ldap.

Calling

```
curl -i -POST 'https://localhost:5443/oauth/token' -d grant_type=password -d username=test@localhost -d password=test -d client_id=client-id-Iegh7ooK  -d client_secret=anynumberyouwant -d scope=sasl_auth
```

Returns a token successfully.

When using the same user within xmpp client using oauth I retrieve "not authorized" and the following error log:

```
2019-12-21 21:19:20.128 [info] <0.370.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:238 (<0.671.0>) Accepted connection 192.168.0.100:2565 -> 192.168.0.231:5222
2019-12-21 21:19:20.248 [warning] <0.671.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_auth_failure:452 (tls|<0.671.0>) Failed c2s X-OAUTH2 authentication for test@domain.local from 192.168.1.100: Invalid token
```

Checking "ejabberdctl oauth_list_tokens" retrievs always an empty list.

What I am missing here ?

Cheers,
Ludwig